# PHP: CEST as timezone

Tags: php, timezone

When calling php in command line with /usr/bin/php, it worries about my timezone settings.
I checked with phpinfo() and looked up the php.ini. I would like to use CEST as timezone and wrote;

`date.timezone = CEST`

Do You see a mistake?

Comment: Can you give a few lines of contextual code, please?

Comment: /usr/bin/php -r "phpinfo();" returns the warning regarding the timezone which is unsafe to take from system time.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
date.timezone = 'Europe/Berlin';
```

will give you what you want. As @nickb has mentioned, 'CEST' is not a supported timezone. Also, do not forget the quotes, it has to be a valid string.

Comment: Is CEST really equivalent to Europe/Berlin? I guess, it's depending on winter/summer while CEST remains on track, isn't it?

Comment: Well, probably, I didn't think that through but I'm not sure if there's a clean solution for your problem then. You could always use **date()** (http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to check if a given date is in Daylight Saving Time and modify your date accordingly.

Comment: You can also use 'UTC' as a timezone which has no Daylight Saving and always add two hours to result in CEST.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that the CEST timezone is not on [the list of supported timezones](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php).

You can use [CET](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php), which is supported, but I'm not sure how that affects your use case.

```
date.timezone = "CET"
```

Comment: this unfortunately ceased to be a valid option. the page itself warns about __"[these timezone codes] only exist for backward compatible reasons, and may expose erroneous behavior."__

Comment: The same for me. While `date.timezone = "CET"` was set, I had a daylight saving issue with twig/symfony, as timezone_type somehow was in one place to 2 in another place 3. On formatting date where timezone_type was 2 a time-zone conversion took place and I got the wrong time … I didn't debug in detail as I already found the mentioned warning for CET and setting to 'Europe/Berlin' solved the issue for me.